# How to add a toolbar to a tableview screen?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a table view controller that is working great, however, I would like to add a toolbar to the bottom of the screen. I understand that I can make a view controller, add a table view then a tool bar inside that view, but then I lose the ability for the navigation bar "edit" button to rearrange the cells.

What can I do? Is there a way to just specify it in the code? I am writing this in swift.

Thanks

Comment: If your table view controller is embedded in a navigation controller, you can have both a navigation bar and a tool bar (which you can turn on in the storyboard).

Comment: How would you turn it on in the storyboard? You're not talking about a tab bar, are you? @rdelmar

Comment: Select the navigation controller, and check the "Shows Toolbar" box in the attributes inspector.

Comment: Wow. I fell incredibly studpid. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Just add following line in viewDidLoad():

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)
```